# Why aren't structures spawning in my flat world?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So im making a custom world and i added some structures, but they aren't spawning. Only nether fortresses and bastions spawn. I tried changing setting, but they still don't spawn (woodland mansions, ocean monuments, and end cities).
If i do `/locate` it crashes.

```
    {
  "type": {
    "name": "minecraft:test",
    "ultrawarm": false,
    "natural": false,
    "piglin_safe": false,
    "respawn_anchor_works": false,
    "bed_works": false,
    "has_raids": false,
    "has_skylight": false,
    "has_ceiling": false,
    "coordinate_scale": 1,
    "ambient_light": 0,
    "logical_height": 256,
    "effects": "minecraft:overworld",
    "infiniburn": "minecraft:infiniburn_overworld"
  },
  "generator": {
    "type": "minecraft:flat",
    "seed": -98454062,
    "settings": {
      "lakes": false,
      "features": false,
      "layers": [
        {
          "block": "minecraft:end_portal_frame",
          "height": 1
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:barrier",
          "height": 2
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:obsidian",
          "height": 1
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:blackstone",
          "height": 10
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:warped_hyphae",
          "height": 2
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:polished_blackstone",
          "height": 2
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:soul_sand",
          "height": 3
        },
        {
          "block": "minecraft:black_stained_glass",
          "height": 1
        }
      ],
      "structures": {
        "structures": {
          "minecraft:bastion_remnant": {
            "spacing": 10,
            "separation": 5,
            "salt": 0
          },
          "minecraft:endcity": {
            "spacing": 2,
            "separation": 1,
            "salt": 0
          },
          "minecraft:fortress": {
            "spacing": 10,
            "separation": 5,
            "salt": 0
          },
          "minecraft:mansion": {
            "spacing": 2,
            "separation": 1,
            "salt": 0
          },
          "minecraft:monument": {
            "spacing": 2,
            "separation": 1,
            "salt": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is probably dumb to ask but is generate structures on?

Comment: yes, i sald it generates fortreses and bastions and villages

Comment: I'm pretty sure bastions and end cities will still only spawn in the nether and end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of testing i found out that my problem was height. The minimal y, that mansions and endcityes to spawn is around 60, sea temples requre water.

Comment: Oh, you mean ocean monuments. That distinction is a bit important, as desert temples (or even jungle temples) come to mind from the term "temple". I'm gonna swap it out in your post for you, don't worry!

Comment: Be sure to mark this answer as accepted so it doesn't appear on the Unanswered queue

Answer (score 0):

Some structures won't spawn in superflat (woodland mansions due to lack of dark forest biome), (ocean monuments due to lack of oceans), but end cities should spawn, not sure what's the problem there.